# Application goes into an infinite loop while trying to retrieve from database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**DBAdapter.java :**

```
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {

                    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mctx,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
                    mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    return this;
                }

                public synchronized void close() {

                    mDBHelper.close();
                }

        public long insertRecord(String firstname, String middlename,
                        String lastname) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
                    cv.put(KEY_MIDDLENAME, middlename);
                    cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lastname);

                    return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

                }



                public int deleteAll(){
                    return mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
                }


                public String getName() {
                    String column[] = new String[] { KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_MIDDLENAME,
                            KEY_LASTNAME };
                    Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null,
                            null);
                    String name = "";
                    int iFirst = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME);
                    int iMiddle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIDDLENAME);
                    int iLast = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME);
                    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToLast()) {
                        name = name + c.getString(iFirst) + "\t" + c.getString(iMiddle)
                                + "\t" + c.getString(iLast) + "\t";
                    }
                    c.close();
                    return name;

                }
```

**Profile_database_view.java :**

```
        db = new DBAdapter(Profile_Database_View.this);
                db.open();
                full_name.setText(db.getName());
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
        dbadapter = new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                        dbadapter.open();
                        dbadapter.insertRecord(first_name, middle_name, last_name);
                        dbadapter.close();
                    }
```

**Logcat :**

```
    12-04 12:10:21.273: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.display_from_database/.Profile_Database_View } from pid 364
    12-04 12:10:21.802: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 704K, 56% free 2693K/6023K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 193ms
    12-04 12:10:22.392: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 971K, 61% free 2656K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 118ms
    12-04 12:10:22.853: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 793K, 60% free 2697K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 14ms+18ms
    12-04 12:10:23.232: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 837K, 60% free 2703K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 26ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:23.482: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 854K, 60% free 2699K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 10ms+10ms
    12-04 12:10:23.714: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 842K, 60% free 2706K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 9ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:23.952: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 838K, 60% free 2711K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 11ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:24.192: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 823K, 60% free 2739K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 10ms+9ms
    12-04 12:10:24.432: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 852K, 60% free 2737K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 13ms+9ms
    12-04 12:10:24.662: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 867K, 60% free 2725K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 10ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:24.912: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 857K, 60% free 2729K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 13ms+6ms
    12-04 12:10:25.122: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 836K, 60% free 2752K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 8ms+8ms
    12-04 12:10:25.352: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 875K, 60% free 2737K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 8ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:25.483: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 914K, 61% free 2670K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 108ms
    12-04 12:10:25.702: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 731K, 59% free 2765K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 8ms+9ms
    12-04 12:10:25.932: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 852K, 59% free 2781K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 11ms+7ms
    12-04 12:10:26.163: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 859K, 59% free 2785K/6727K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 9ms+7ms
```

I am able to insert the data into the database but while retrieving it goes into this 
infinite loop and my app turns into a blank black screen. Has anybody come across this ?

Help me guys. This keeps happening to me for a while and googling said that i am doing 
some intensive process with CPU but it is as simple as retrieving a database.

Comment: getName() while accesing this method its going in infinte loop?

Comment: Your first mistake is that you use `c.moveToLast()` as your incrementing step instead of `c.moveToNext()` but that shouldn't be the cause of looping.

Comment: @Techfist Yes,getName() is the method that's causing the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes, to put both answers together - your mistake is that your condition is to reach `c.isAfterLast()`, however you increment it to `c.moveToLast()` which will never go one step after the last. So either change the condition or change the incrementing step to `c.moveToNext()` and you'll be fine.
Good luck!

Comment: Guys, you were right. for loop was the culprit and now its solved. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your for loop

> for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToLast())

did c.moveToLast() do something?

Comment: True, the incrementer should be `c.moveToNext()`

Comment: @user974801, No that just checks whether the cursor has reached the last point. But i have tried the same loop with implicitly inserting the data (hard coding the insertmethod) but that works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You for loop is suspicious, if you want through iterate through cusrsor, always use do while. e.g

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){

   do{
       // You code for reading from cursor
     }while(cursor.moveToNext());

}
```

this will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

// Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
// you will actually use after this query.
String[] projection = {
    COLUMN_ID,
    KEY_FIRSTNAME,  
    KEY_MIDDLENAME,
    KEY_LASTNAME
    };




Cursor c = db.query(
    TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
    projection,                               // The columns to return
    selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
    selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,                                     // don't group the rows
    null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
    null                                 // The sort order
    );
```

Try this out .... in selection and selected arguments implements your conditiona if you need

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop change your  last condition `c.moveToLast()` to `c.moveToNext()`

Try out as below:

```
   public String getName() {
                String column[] = new String[] { KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_MIDDLENAME,
                        KEY_LASTNAME };
                Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null,
                        null);
                String name = "";
                for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) 
                {
                  int iFirst = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME);
                  int iMiddle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIDDLENAME);
                   int iLast = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME);

                    name = name + c.getString(iFirst) + "\t" + c.getString(iMiddle)
                            + "\t" + c.getString(iLast) + "\t";
                }
                c.close();
                return name;

            }
```